# Как обработать ошибку “log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger”?

Tags: java, log4j

Я хочу перехватить эту ошибку, что бы можно было "подставить" конфигурацию log4j для случая "по-умолчанию", когда стандартный файл конфигурации не найден там, где он должен был быть. Это возможно?

Comment: это не ошибка, а варнинг.

Comment: Нужно не перехватывать, а написать свою реализацию класса, который конфигурирует log4j, в котором как раз и проверить наличие стандартного файла, и если его нет подставить дефолтный.

Comment: @enzo, есть какие-нибудь примеры, что-то почитать на эту тему?

Comment: Это вопрос для шоу экстрасенсов. :) Вы не указали ни версию log4j, ни что у вас за приложение и кто инициализирует логгер. Читать нужно документацию log4j и вашего фреймворка, если он есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно спрятать WARNIG (No appenders...) в случае отсутствия файла и загрузить конфигурации по умолчанию:

```
public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    URL propertiesUrl = Main.class.getResource("/log4j.properties");
    if (propertiesUrl == null) {
        //Hide no appender warning
        Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);
        log.info("Load default logger properties");
        updateLog4jConfiguration();
        log.info("Default logger properties are loaded");
    }

    log.info("Main method is started.");

}

private static void updateLog4jConfiguration() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try (InputStream configStream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream( "/default.properties"))  {
        props.load(configStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Errornot laod configuration file ");
    }
    LogManager.resetConfiguration();
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
}
```

Чтобы скрыть WARNIN Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF); должно быть вызвано до первого сообщения в лог иначе увидем WARNING в stderr.
Я использовал примерно такие конфигурации по умолчанию:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.my.test.logger=INFO
```

Можно увидеть, что после обновления свойств логи начинают выводиться в stdout.